# Perl way of iterating over 2 arrays in parallel

Tags: perl

I used

```
Use List::MoreUtils qw(each_array);
my $it = each_array( @input_dump_arr, @created_dump_arr);
while ( my ($first, $second) = $it->()) {
}
```

Would this work in a default perl configuration? 
A broader question is are there guidelines to write "portable" perl scripts? I'm new to Perl, just trying to figure out if cpan is actually analogous to how boost libraries are to c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use this simpler rewrite of the module's `each_arrayref` function. `each_array` is a superfluous wrapper around this function that uses prototypes to take references to arrays passed as parameters.

Its functionality is identical to the module version, except that it does no checking of the parameters it receives, and the iterator returned doesn't check that it has either no parameters or `'index'`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub each_array {

  my @copy = @_;
  my $i;
  my $max;

  for (map scalar @$_, @copy) {
    $max = $_ unless defined $max and $max > $_;
  }

  sub {
    return $i if @_ and shift eq 'index';
    my $new_i = defined $i ? $i + 1 : 0;
    return if $new_i >= $max;
    $i = $new_i;
    return map $_->[$i], @copy;
  }
}

my @array1 = qw/ A B C /;
my @array2 = qw/ D E F G /;

my $iter = each_array(\@array1, \@array2);

while (my @values = $iter->()) {
  printf "%d: %s\n", $iter->('index'), join ', ', map $_ // 'undef', @values;
}
```

**output**

```
0: A, D
1: B, E
2: C, F
3: undef, G
```

You could, of course, simply take the code for `each_arrayref` from the `List::MoreUtils` module. It is self-contained and will guarantee compatibility with your existing code.

Comment: Is there any we can iterate two arrays using while loop without using any cpam module?

Answer (score 7):

It's not a core module (meaning it's not bundled with perl), but it's a relatively common one. I wouldn't hesitate to use it.

If you are *really* paranoid it might not be available, assuming arrays are the **same size**, you can use something like the following:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#array1) {
  my $first  = $array1[$i];
  my $second = $array2[$i];
}
```

However, fortunately each_array() is implemented in pure perl, so you could also view the source of List/MoreUtils.pm and copy and paste the relevant subroutines.

Comment: Is there any we can iterate two arrays using while loop without using any cpam module?

Answer (score 2):

There are modules distributed directly with Perl itself. They're usually called "core modules". You can always use those. `List::Util` is one of them, though `List::MoreUtils` is not.

However, `List::MoreUtils` is a module available on [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org). CPAN is often considered to be "Perl's standard library", similar to what "the Standard Library" is for C++. Most people think it's OK to require users of their application to have certain modules installed from CPAN, especially if they're well-used modules.

`List::MoreUtils` is definitely a well-used module. It's been around for quite some time. All major Linux distributions that I know of contain packaged versions of it.

So if your goal is not to be 100% independent of non-core modules then I strongly suggest that you do continue using `List::MoreUtils` and most of the other fine modules available on CPAN. They're why Perl rocks.

Slightly offtopic: I have to admit that I prefer `pairwise` (also from `List::MoreUtils`) for exactly two arrays because it behaves more like `map`. For your example:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(pairwise);
pairwise { do_stuff($a, $b) } @input_dump_arr, @created_dump_arr;
```

Comment: And if you don't want to require `List::MoreUtils`, you can still just [copy the parts you like](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/List-MoreUtils-0.33_007/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) into your application.