# Is it possible to assign two variables in Perl foreach loop?

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, variables, foreach

Is it possible to assign two variables the same data from an array in a Perl foreach loop?

I am using Perl 5, I think I came across something in Perl 6.

Something like this:

```
my $var1;
my $var2;

foreach $var1,$var2 (@array){...}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html)?  It illustrates `while (($key,$value) = each %ENV) {
        print "$key=$value\n";
    }` amongst other words of wisdom.  Beware of the resetting behaviour.  See also [Why doesn't Perl's `each` iterate through the entire hash the second time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123693/why-doesnt-perls-each-iterate-through-the-entire-hash-the-second-time)

Answer (score 17):

It's not in the Perl 5 core language, but [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) has a `pairs` function which should be close enough (and a number of other `pair...` functions which may be more convenient, depending on what you're doing inside the loop):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use List::Util 'pairs';

my @list = qw(a 1 b 2 c 3);

for my $pair (pairs @list) {
  my ($first, $second) = @$pair;
  say "$first => $second";
}
```

Output:

```
a => 1
b => 2
c => 3
```

Comment: List::Util is a core module since Perl 5.7.3. So it can be assumed to be installe.

Comment: @BarneySchmale - Yeah, I wasn't quite sure how to word that clearly. It's part of the core _distribution_ (you don't have to install from CPAN), but not part of the core _language_ (you do have to explicitly `use` the module). I'm open to suggestions (or edits) for better ways to say that in the answer.

Comment: @BarneySchmale You can count on List::Util but not on the List::Pairwise API, which was added only very recently.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to use this is with a `while` loop that calls `splice` on the first two elements of the array each time,

```
while (my($var1, $var2) = splice(@array, 0, 2)) {
    ...
}
```

However, unlike `foreach`, this continually does a double-shift on the original array, so when you’re done, the array is empty.  Also, the variables assigned are copies, not aliases as with `foreach`.

If you don’t like that, you can use a C-style `for` loop:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @array; $i += 2) {
     my($var1, $var2) = @array[$i, $i+1];
     ...
}
```

That leaves the array in place but **does not allow you to update it** the way `foreach` does.  To do that, you need to address the array directly.

```
my @pairlist = (
    fee => 1,
    fie => 2,
    foe => 3,
    fum => 4,
);

for (my $i = 0; $i < @pairlist; $i += 2) {
    $pairlist[ $i + 0 ] x= 2;
    $pairlist[ $i + 1 ] *= 2;
}

print "Array is @pairlist\n";
```

That prints out:

```
Array is feefee 2 fiefie 4 foefoe 6 fumfum 8
```

You ***can*** get those into aliased variables if you try hard enough, but it’s probably not worth it:

```
my @kvlist = ( 
    fee => 1,
    fie => 2,
    foe => 3,
    fum => 4,
);

for (my $i = 0; $i < @kvlist; $i += 2) { 
    our  ($key, $value);
    local(*key, $value) = \@kvlist[ $i, $i + 1 ];
    $key   x= 2;
    $value *= 2;
}

print "Array is @kvlist\n";
```

Which prints out the expected changed array:

```
Array is feefee 2 fiefie 4 foefoe 6 fumfum 8
```

Note that the pairs offered by the [List::Pairwise](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Pairwise) module, which were but ***very* recently** added to the core [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) module (and so you probably cannot use it), are still not giving you aliases:

```
use List::Util 1.29 qw(pairs);

my @pairlist = (
    fee => 1,
    fie => 2,
    foe => 3,
    fum => 4,
);

for my $pref (pairs(@pairlist)) {
    $pref->[0] x= 2;
    $pref->[1] *= 2;
}

print "Array is @pairlist\n";
```

That prints out only:

```
Array is fee 1 fie 2 foe 3 fum 4
```

So it didn’t change the array at all.  Oops. :(

Of course, if this were a real hash, you could double the values trivially:

```
for my $value (values %hash) { $value *= 2 }
```

The reasons that works is because those are aliases into the actual hash values.

You cannot change the keys, since they’re immutable.  However, you can make a new hash that’s an updated copy of the old one easily enough:

```
my %old_hash = (
    fee => 1,
    fie => 2,
    foe => 3,
    fum => 4,
);

my %new_hash;    
@new_hash{ map { $_ x 2 } keys   %old_hash } = 
           map { $_ * 2 } values %old_hash;

print "Old hash is: ", join(" " => %old_hash), "\n";
print "New hash is: ", join(" " => %new_hash), "\n";
```

That outputs

```
Old hash is: foe 3 fee 1 fum 4 fie 2
New hash is: foefoe 6 fiefie 4 fumfum 8 feefee 2
```

Answer (score 3):

A general algorithm for more than 2 variables:

```
while( @array ){
  my $var1 = shift @array;
  my $var2 = shift @array;
  my $var3 = shift @array;
  # other variables from @array

  # do things with $var1, $var2, $var3, ...
}
```

PS: Using a working copy of the array to that it is preserved for use later:

```
if( my @working_copy = @array ){
  while( @working_copy ){
    my $var1 = shift @working_copy;
    my $var2 = shift @working_copy;
    my $var3 = shift @working_copy;
    # other variables from @working_copy

    # do things with $var1, $var2, $var3, ...
  }
}
```

PPS: another way is to use indexing. Of course, that is a sure sign that the data structure is wrong. It should be an array of arrays (AoA) or an array of hashes (AoH). See [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and [perldoc perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).

```
my $i = 0;
while( $i < @array ){
  my $var1 = $array[ $i++ ];
  my $var2 = $array[ $i++ ];
  my $var3 = $array[ $i++ ];
  # other variables from @array

  # do things with $var1, $var2, $var3, ...
}
```

PPPS: I've been asked to clarify why the data structure is wrong. It is a flatten set of tuples (aka records aka datasets). The tuples are recreated by counting of the number of data for each. But what is the reader constructing the set has a bug and doesn't always get the number right? If, for a missing value, it just skips adding anything? Then all the remaining tuples are shifted by one, causing the following tuples to be grouped incorrectly and therefore, invalid. That is why an AoA is better; only the tuple with the missing data would be invalid.

But an better structure would be an AoH. Each datum would access by a key. Then new or optional data can be added without breaking the code downstream.

While I'm at it, I'll add some code examples:

```
# example code for AoA
for my $tuple ( @aoa ){
  my $var1 = $tuple->[0];
  my $var2 = $tuple->[1];
  my $var3 = $tuple->[2];
  # etc
}

# example code for AoH
for my $tuple ( @aoh ){
  my $var1 = $tuple->{keyname1};
  my $var2 = $tuple->{key_name_2};
  my $var3 = $tuple->{'key name with spaces'};
  my $var4 = $tuple->{$key_name_in_scalar_variable};
  # etc
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that after this loop has completed `@array` will be empty.  A `foreach` loop doesn't have that side effect.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not saying your code is bad or wrong, just that the OP originally asked about a `foreach` loop. And one point of difference between your solution and a `foreach` loop is that your code removes items from the array. Not wrong, just different - hence "worth noting".

Comment: Nice, simple, unlikely to break ... ++  I like to preserve the original and work on a copy. Hmm ...  `my @xyz = "A" .. "Z" ;  my @tmp = @xyz ; while( @tmp ){ my $alpha = shift @tmp; my $beta = shift @tmp ; say "$alpha  $beta " }`  ??

Comment: Can you make more clear in your response what you mean by " that is a sure sign that the data structure is wrong"?  You don't have to do it for me since I already up voted you ... but it might get you more votes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a module-less way to "loop" by an arbitrary value (`$by`) and output the resulting group of elements using an array slice:

```
#!perl -l
@array = "1".."6"; 
$by = 3; $by--; 

for (my $i = 0 ; $i < @array ; $i += $by ) { 
      print "@array[$i..$i+$by]"; 
      $i++ ;
}
```

As a one-liner to test (cut and paste to a Unix shell):

```
perl -E '@array = "1".."6"; $by = 3; $by--; 
      for (my $i = 0 ; $i < @array ; $i += $by ) { 
      say "@array[$i..$i+$by]"; $i++ }'
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

If you make `$by = 2;` it will print pairs of numbers. To get at specific elements of the resulting slice access it as an anonymous array: (*e.g.* `[@array[$i..$i+$by]]->[1]`).

**See also:**

- [How do I read two items at a time in a Perl foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569772/how-do-i-read-two-items-at-a-time-in-a-perl-foreach-loop)
- [Perl way of iterating over 2 arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024480/perl-way-of-iterating-over-2-arrays-in-parallel)

Some good responses there, including reference to `natatime` which is quite easy to use. It's easy to implement too - it is essentially a wrapper around the `splice` solutions mentioned in the responses here.

The following is not the nicest example, but I've been using [`autobox::Core`](https://metacpan.org/pod/autobox::Core) and made an `@array->natatime()` "method" ;-) like this:

```
use autobox::Core ;
sub autobox::Core::ARRAY::natatime {
  my ($self, $by) = @_; 
  my @copy = @$self ;
  my @array ;

  push @array, [splice (@copy, 0, $by) ] while @copy ;

  if  ( not defined wantarray ) { 
      print "@{ $_ } \n" for @array ;
  } 

  return wantarray ? @array : \@array;      
}
```

The `@copy` array is `spliced` destructively, but `$self` (which is how the `@array` in front of the autobox method `->` arrow gets passed to the function) is still there. So I can do:

```
my @dozen = "1" .. "12" ;           # cakes to eat
@dozen->natatime(4)  ;              # eat 4 at time
my $arr_ref = @dozen->natatime(4) ; # make a reference
say "Group 3: @{ $arr_ref->[2] }" ; # prints a group of elements
say scalar @dozen , " cakes left" ; # eat cake; still have it
```

**Output**:

```
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 
Group 3: 9 10 11 12
12 cakes left
```

One other approach that also uses a CPAN module (I gave [this answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29834175/2019415) but it is worth repeating). This can also be done non-destructively, with [Eric Strom's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189416/eric-strom) excellent [`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Gen) module:

```
perl -MList::Gen=":all" -E '@n = "1".."6"; say "@$_" for every 2 => @n'
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Each group of elements you grab is returned in an anonymous array so the individual values are in: `$_->[0] $_->[1] ...` *etc*.

---

You mentioned Perl6, which handles multiple looping values nicely:

```
my @qarr = 1 .. 6;
my ($x, $y, $z) ;
for @qarr -> $x , $y , $z { say $x/$y  ; say "z = " ~ $z }
```

**Output:**

```
0.5
z = 3
0.8
z = 6
```

For more on the Perl6 approach see: [Looping for Fun and Profit](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2009/12/07/day-7-looping-for-fun-and-profit/) from the 2009 Perl6 Advent Calendar, or the [Blocks and Statements Synopsis](http://design.perl6.org/S04.html#The_for_statement) for details. Perhaps Perl 5 will have a similar "loop by multliple values" construct one day - *à la* [perl5i's `foreach`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5i#foreach) :-)